# Best practice for passing data to service layer

Tags: spring, design-patterns, spring-mvc

I am working on a web application in spring following the MVC pattern and was wondering what  is considered "best practice" for making a solid  service layer. The reason for this question is the following example situation:

A page for editing user information is loaded. After this form is submitted I gather all of its data in my controller method in a specific Command class containing only the data needed for the action that follows (updating the user).

I can think of several situations now to pass this information to my service layer:

- Passing the command itself: userService.save(command);
- Passing a model class, fetched in the controller: userService.save(user);
- Passing both a model class and the command: userService.save(user, command);
- Passing all of the parameters individually: userService.save(command.getName(), ...)

In my opinion passing the command class itself looks like the most elegant solution as I can first validate all the values automatically using the framework then pass them to my service. My concern here is that when I call the method from another class (not through my form / controller) I can fill this command object with invalid data, resulting in possible errors in the service layer.

What would you recommend and why?

Comment: Either the service layer trusts te layer calling it, and dosn't validate the command, or it doesn't trust it, and should validate te data it receives. You just need to clearly define the responsibilities of each layer. Whatever you do, you will always be able to pass invalid data. Make tests to make sure you don't.

Answer (score 1):

After seeing your I have the following ideas
Passing the command itself: userService.save(command);

> This may not be a goode idea since your Service layer is unnecessarily
>   dependent on Command object

```
Passing a model class, fetched in the controller: userService.save(user);
```

> I will vote for this. Service layer only what it really supposed to
>   know

```
Passing both a model class and the command: userService.save(user, command);
```

> No. Same as the first option

```
Passing all of the parameters individually: userService.save(command.getName(), ...)
```

> Hmmmm... not sure.. May be a mainitenance overhead in future.

```
I think if you want to do the validation, Use validation util classes to do the validation 
    which can be used for both Service and UI layer. Here a lot validation can be centralized.
```

Answer (score 0):

In his MVC book, Dino Esposito recommends creating a 'worker' class that takes and returns a viewmodel. The controller calls the worker with the viewmodel and then the worker delegates as necessary. I've not used it in practise but in theory it appears to be a nice solution.

Answer (score 0):

Any option using your Command object will cause trouble. It breaks loose coupling. Now your service layer is tightly coupled with service layer. Please don't do it.

(EDIT: In my answer below, when I say Model for presentation layer I am talking about View Model and for service layer it is the Domain Model)
Sending your Model object looks like a good option. But, it depends on how the model was created.  Some times, presentation layer will need a different model structure and the service layer will need a moderatley/completely different structure.

If both layers have different needs, then you need to create 2 model structure. This way service layer's model structure doesn't have to change when presentation layer changed. This is important as the service may have multiple consumers and may not be able to change when presentation layer changes.

If they don't have different structure, I would still create them from service layer point of view as service is the real reusable component here.

Answer (score 0):

A good pattern to follow when dealing with commands in multi-layered systems is to have a CommandBus service that routes your commands to their specific handlers. That way, you decouple your controller from your services (while coupling it with a generic routing system).

`commandBus.handle(command);`

You must do additional work in configuring the command bus handlers, but it will pay in the long term when you'll be able to reuse that routing information:

`commandBus.register(commandType, handlerService);`

and you may then be able to move the validation of the commands in the `commandBus` service (even though this will mean some mixing of concerns for the commandBus)

`commandBus.registerValidator(commandType, validatorsCollection);`